# C++ Button with transparent background

Tags: c++, winapi, button

I'm creating a basic application in C++ (Win32 API). I tried to make a button with the CreateWindow() function as seen below:

```
button1 = CreateWindow("button", TEXT("Click Me!"), WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 100, 200, 70, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

The problem is that there is a white border around the button as you can see here:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXVFL.jpg)

I tried to make it transparent with this code but is doesn't work.

```
case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:{
    HBRUSH hBrushbtn;
    hBrushbtn = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    SetBkMode((HDC) wParam, TRANSPARENT);
    return ((LRESULT)hBrushbtn);
    break;
}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetBkMode()` affects whether or not text rendering is transparent or not, which is not the issue here.

You're going to have to `WM_PRINTCLIENT` up to the parent control into the button's DC, [as I demonstrate here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25551622/3408572). (Note that my code still calls `SetBkMode()` for transparent text in checkboxes, groupboxes, labels, etc.; for pushbuttons it won't matter if you're using visual styles).

Comment: Thanks! WM_PRINTCLIENT did the job.