# Brush origin, PatBlt(), and MapWindowRect() confusion

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

Continuing from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319918/once-and-for-all-how-do-i-get-a-fully-transparent-checkbox-button-radio-butto) with a little help from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5978/Correctly-drawn-themed-dialogs-in-WinXP), I have the following code, which is part of a custom container window class and should draw its parent as its background, to fake transparency:

```
static HBRUSH getControlBackgroundBrush(HWND hwnd, HDC dc, RECT *hwndScreenRect)
{
    HWND parent;
    RECT parentRect;
    int class;
    HDC cdc;
    HBITMAP bitmap, prevbitmap;
    HBRUSH brush;

    parent = hwnd;
    for (;;) {
        parent = GetAncestor(parent, GA_PARENT);
        // skip groupboxes; they're (supposed to be) transparent
        // skip nested containers; they don't draw anything
        // note: returns 0 if parent's class is L"button", 1 if containerClass, -1 if neither
        class = windowClassOf(parent, L"button", containerClass, NULL);
        if (class != 0 && class != 1)
            break;
    }

    if (GetClientRect(parent, &parentRect) == 0)
        logLastError("error getting parent's client rect in getControlBackgroundBrush()");

    cdc = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
    if (cdc == NULL)
        logLastError("error creating compatible DC in getControlBackgroundBrush()");
    bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, parentRect.right - parentRect.left, parentRect.bottom - parentRect.top);
    if (bitmap == NULL)
        logLastError("error creating compatible bitmap in getControlBackgroundBrush()");
    prevbitmap = SelectObject(cdc, bitmap);
    if (prevbitmap == NULL)
        logLastError("error selecting bitmap into compatible DC in getControlBackgroundBrush()");
    SendMessageW(parent, WM_PRINTCLIENT, (WPARAM) cdc, PRF_CLIENT);
    // create it now, just to be safe
    brush = CreatePatternBrush(bitmap);
    if (brush == NULL)
        logLastError("error creating pattern brush in getControlBackgroundBrush()");
    if (SelectObject(cdc, prevbitmap) != bitmap)
        logLastError("error selecting previous bitmap back into compatible DC in getControlBackgroundBrush()");
    if (DeleteObject(bitmap) == 0)
        logLastError("error deleting compatible bitmap in getControlBackgroundBrush()");
    if (DeleteDC(cdc) == 0)
        logLastError("error deleting compatible DC in getControlBackgroundBrush()");

    // the given control rect is in screen coordinates; convert to parent coordinates
    MapWindowRect(NULL, parent, hwndScreenRect);
    if (SetBrushOrgEx(dc, -hwndScreenRect->left, -hwndScreenRect->top, NULL) == 0)
        logLastError("error setting brush origin in getControlBackgroundBrush()");

    return brush;
}

// TODO this doesn't work right for partial redraws
static void paintContainerBackground(HWND hwnd, HDC dc, RECT *paintRect)
{
    RECT screenRect;
    HBRUSH brush, prevbrush;

    // getControlBackgroundBrush() needs a screen rectangle
    screenRect = *paintRect;
    MapWindowRect(hwnd, NULL, &screenRect);
    brush = getControlBackgroundBrush(hwnd, dc, &screenRect);
    prevbrush = SelectObject(dc, brush);
    if (prevbrush == NULL)
        logLastError("error selecting background brush into DC in paintContainerBackground()");
    if (PatBlt(dc, paintRect->left, paintRect->top, paintRect->right - paintRect->left, paintRect->bottom - paintRect->top, PATCOPY) == 0)
        logLastError("error drawing container background in paintContainerBackground()");
    if (SelectObject(dc, prevbrush) != brush)
        logLastError("error selecting previous brush back into DC in paintContainerBackground()");
    if (DeleteObject(brush) == 0)
        logLastError("error deleting background brush in paintContainerBackground()");
}

    // window procedure
    case WM_PAINT:
        if (cc == NULL)
            break;
        c = (struct container *) (uiControl(cc)->Internal);
        dc = BeginPaint(c->hwnd, &ps);
        if (dc == NULL)
            logLastError("error beginning container paint in containerWndProc()");
        r = ps.rcPaint;
        paintContainerBackground(c->hwnd, dc, &r);
        EndPaint(c->hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
```

In the test program for this container class's parent library, I have a row of buttons and another button to hide them. Hiding moves the button that hides up; showing moves it back down.

Preemptive note: the screenshots below use Windows XP as the gradient its tab control uses as a background is perfect for both testing the above code and demonstrating bugs like the one I'm asking about.

Now, if I'm understanding correctly, the two `MapWindowRect()` calls will convert the given client rect portion to the parent's client rect coordinates, so the `SetBrushOrgEx()` will set the brush origin to the upper-left corner of the given client rect portion, and the `PatBlt()` will draw that at the real upper-left corner.

When drawing *the entire container*, this seems to work fine.

But when I hide the row of buttons, the update rect is smaller than the entire client rect. And instead of drawing the correct portion of the background, I get something else background instead:

[image: Incorrect output]

It depends on the height of the window; in this case, the window is somewhat tall so the rectangle isn't as visible; if the window was shorter it would be white (obviously near the top of the background).

Now, if I ignore the update rect entirely and client -> screen conversion and just use the window rect directly:

```
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, hwndScreenRect);
    // the given control rect is in screen coordinates; convert to parent coordinates
    MapWindowRect(NULL, parent, hwndScreenRect);
    if (SetBrushOrgEx(dc, -hwndScreenRect->left, -hwndScreenRect->top, NULL) == 0)
        logLastError("error setting brush origin in getControlBackgroundBrush()");
```

then everything *seems to* work fine:

[image: Correct output, or so it seems]

So: what am I misunderstanding about the way the `MapWindowRect()`s, `SetBrushOrgEx()`, and `PatBlt()` that causes the first code to not work right? Why does the second code work? Given my idea of how everything should work, it shouldn't...

Thanks. (Hopefully this all came off without being unclear.)

Comment: I don't remember my Windows XP, but it wasn't this hard. Just use `DrawThemeBackground`, etc. Other versions of Windows don't use this so you could skip it altogether.

Comment: By other do you mean older or newer? I'm only using Windows XP because its tab background is optimal for testing drawing like this; I might drop XP support entirely in the future, but newer Windows is still necessary. As for using `DrawThemeBackground()`, I don't know if the container is going to be inside a tab control or the top-level window (which isn't drawn with uxtheme). Unless you mean I should have multiple code paths?

Comment: Or maybe I could try switching back to using `WM_PRINTCLIENT` for this case (but not the `WM_CTLCOLORxxx` handlers, since that's giving me weird blanking bugs; hopefully they don't come back if I do this though)...

Comment: Actually that turns out to be a much better solution than what I was trying to do! I guess I was too focused on reusing the working `WM_CTLCOLORxxx` code I already had to realize I could just use `WM_PRINTCLIENT` (or `DrawThemeBackground()`; same difference) directly. (No button click redraw issues either.) Thanks @BarmakShemirani!

Comment: I am not sure what is happening but I am glad I managed to talk you of this :-) From Windows Vista to Win8, there is no gradient background for tabs. The tab-area background is solid-color `GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW)` and dialog background is `COLOR_BTNFACE`. For Windows XP, you can force the tab's background to be `COLOR_WINDOW` if it's making trouble, it will ugly line-up on top but it's no big deal. I haven't seen Windows 10.

Comment: It's not making any trouble. I'm saying the gradient allows me to make sure my drawing code is working correctly (by making sure the gradient is aligned to where it should be), so it's a very useful debugging tool that comes "free".